# How to change the theme to dark in Google Colab?

Tags: themes, google-colaboratory

How do I change the current theme to the dark theme in Google Colab?

I need a dark theme like Jupyter notebook has.

Comment: The issue to follow is https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/90 It also includes some work-arounds.

Comment: What's the work-arounds? I don't see any discussion or information.

Comment: First of all, as the person who formulated the git request, I have no idea why your question was downvoted, a dark theme is clearly a necessity.

Second, at the moment I tried using chrome/firefox extensions, for night mode (or dark mode). Just search for dark background in the extension store. That does not seem to look nice though, so we have to wait.

Comment: This question has been downvoted and closed because it was linked from meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381591/should-this-question-about-changing-color-settings-in-google-colab-remain-open-o

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. From the top menu, select Tools -> Settings,
2. From Site, select "Dark" in the theme dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## Cats & Dogs

And if you were searching for the cat & dogs running around at the top of your notebook, then you can add them by following these steps:

- Open any Colab notebook.
- Click on `Tools` -> `setting` -> `Miscellaneous`
- And check `Corgi mode` if you want just dogs or `Kitty mode` if you want just cats or both if you're a human being:

[image]

And you'll have them running around all-day long

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this path in colab

##tools -> settings -> site -> theme## [how widow look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfZyq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dark theme from userstyles.org if you have the [Stylus plugin](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) installed:

https://userstyles.org/styles/168225/dark-theme-for-google-colab-development

Comment: [The Stylish browser extension steals all your internet history](https://robertheaton.com/2018/07/02/stylish-browser-extension-steals-your-internet-history/). A better alternative (that I have not tried myself) might be [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus)

Answer (score 0):

Google colab's UI is updated occasionally. Until the time this answer was written, you could change the theme using the following steps:

1. From the top menu, select settings.
2. From settings, select site.
3. You can choose one of the three listed options: light, dark or adaptive.

[Illustrating Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12YsD.png)

let your eyes enjoy the dark theme!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

From the top menu, select Tools -> Settings,
From Site, select "Dark" in the theme dropdown.